# error: value succinct is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]

Tags: search, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying out succinctRDD for searching mechanism.
Below is what I am trying as per the doc:

```
import edu.berkeley.cs.succinct.kv._
val data = sc.textFile("file:///home/aman/data/jsonDoc1.txt")
val succintdata = data.succinct.persist()
```

The link is here ...[succint RDD](http://succinct.cs.berkeley.edu/wp/wordpress/)

The error I am getting is below

```
<console>:32: error: value succinct is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
         val succintdata = data.succinct.persist()
```

if anybody can point out the problem here or any step I should follow before this.

This is basically sbt build .

```
name := "succinttest"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
resolvers += "Spark Packages Repo" at "http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "1.5.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka_2.11" % "0.8.2.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "1.5.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "1.5.2"
libraryDependencies += "amplab" % "succinct" % "0.1.7"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.6.0" excludeAll ExclusionRule(organization = "javax.servlet")
```

Comment: How about calling .map(_.getBytes) on sx.textFile(..) ?

Comment: and what about your build file ? build.sbt or pom.xml

Comment: @eliasah This is build.sbt

Comment: I mean can you add it to your question details ?

Comment: @eliasah I think the problem is an outdated article, if you check the source code the implicit conversion is from SparkContext, there is no implicit conversion from RDD[String] or RDD[Array[Byte]].

Comment: would you care sharing a data sample ? I might have an idea of what's wrong.

Comment: The error is explicative itself... Scala doesn't find any implicit conversion from RDD[String], review my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical implicit conversion problem in Scala.

When you import the library:

```
import edu.berkeley.cs.succinct.kv._
```

Then your are importing all the classes/methods from this package, and then all the implicits. So, if you check the package.object on the source:
https://github.com/amplab/succinct/blob/master/spark/src/main/scala/edu/berkeley/cs/succinct/kv/package.scala

... then you will realize that you have the next implicit conversion:

```
implicit class SuccinctContext(sc: SparkContext) {
  def succinctKV[K: ClassTag](filePath: String, storageLevel: StorageLevel = StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY) 
  (implicit ordering: Ordering[K])
  : SuccinctKVRDD[K] = SuccinctKVRDD[K](sc, filePath, storageLevel)
}
```

Which means that you have a new method on SparkContext to create a new SuccinctKVRDD from a text file. So try the next code:

```
import edu.berkeley.cs.succinct.kv._
val data = sc.succinctKV("file:///home/aman/data/jsonDoc1.txt")
```

And then you will have a succint RDD to do all the operations that you need like search, filterByValue, etc:
https://github.com/amplab/succinct/blob/master/spark/src/main/scala/edu/berkeley/cs/succinct/kv/SuccinctKVRDD.scala